# jquery Remove html tags from html string

Tags: jquery

I need to load an html string into memory from the page and remove divs that have a certain class using jQuery.

What I am trying to do is below but it doesn't work.

```
var reportHTML = $('#collapsereportsdata').html()
$(reportHTML).(".dontprintme").each().remove();
```

Thanks

Comment: does it work without the each() ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the HTML with the tags removed you can [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element and remove the elements you don't want before getting it's HTML, like this:

```
var newHTML = $('#collapsereportsdata').clone().find(".dontprintme")
                                               .remove().end().html();
```

This performs a [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) of the original element, does a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the elements you want to [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), then uses [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to jump back to the cloned element, since that's the one you'd want to get the html via [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) from.