# Looking for a way in jquery to stack lines of text with a diagonal left edge

Tags: jquery

Basically this question is similar to this post: [Display Paragraph's text with Diagonal Indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257417/display-paragraphs-text-with-diagonal-indent)

but with some key differences, I'm looking to have a fixed line width for each line because I feel that will help the wrapping process, I'm defining the width of each line as 600px and at that point any word that runs past the 600px mark will wrap in down to the next line which will be indented more and more each time - to crrate the diagonal left edge. The code will need to detect all standard characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and all punctuation to be wrapped.

Here is some code (below) I have bodged together, it kind of does what I want but is a bit buggy and I'm sure it's not best practice; it's a bit long and could be reduced in size significantly (do I really need to duplicate the paragraph or programmatically create spans to get this to work?!). I think it has problems detecting hyphens and the lines could be programatically indented too. I tried to look into the regex so as to include looking for hyphens in the code but it just seemed too 'full on'! I couldn't understand.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

James

Here is a link to my site:

http://jimmysmooth.byethost7.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery.fn.wrapLines = function( openTag, closeTag )
  {
    var dummy = this.clone().css({
            top: -9999,
            left: -9999,
            position: 'absolute',
            width: this.width()
        }).appendTo(this.parent())
      , text = dummy.text().match(/\S+\s+/g);

    var words = text.length
      , lastTopOffset = 0
      , lines = []
      , lineText = ''
    ;

    for ( var i = 0; i < words; ++i )
    {
      dummy.html(
          text.slice(0,i).join('') +
          text[i].replace(/(\S)/, '$1<span/>') +
          text.slice(i+1).join('')
      );

      var topOffset = jQuery( 'span', dummy ).offset().top;

      if ( topOffset !== lastTopOffset && i != 0 )
      {
        lines.push( lineText );
        lineText = text[i];
      } else {
        lineText += text[i];
      }

      lastTopOffset = topOffset;
    }
    lines.push( lineText );

    this.html( openTag + lines.join( closeTag + openTag ) + closeTag );
  };

  $(function()
  {
    $('p').wrapLines( '<span class="line">', '</span>' );
     $('p span:nth-child(2)').css('margin-left', '20px');
        $('p span:nth-child(3)').css('margin-left', '40px');
            $('p span:nth-child(4)').css('margin-left', '60px');
  });

</script>

<style type="text/css">


#back {
    height: 100px;
    width: 717px;
    background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat;
    outline: 1px #FFCC00 dotted;
    color: #FFF;
    font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

p {
    bottom:0;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    outline: 1px #FFCC00 dotted;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    /*vertical-align: baseline;*/
}
</style>

<body>

<div id="back">
<div id=""vert>
<p style="width: 600px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehender.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```